# Mocking blockchain for unit test quorum

Tags: solidity, testrpc, quorum, unittesting, truffle-test

Is there a way so that I can mock blockchain for unit test in quorum.
I do not want to set up a test blockchain for unit testing. Is there any possibility.

Comment: I don't know if you already tried this http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Comment: My question is regarding mocking blockchain for unit testing... Above link is  imteo about Quorum

Comment: Best tool for mocking blockchain for unit tests is Ganache. Did you test this?

Comment: Using ganache/truffle to test Quorum is a lot more complicated than normal testing, and is probably why OP doesn't want to use it, see http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains. You're best choice is to use the SimulatedBackend package build into Quorum.

Answer (score 1):

Since Quorum is essentially running the EVM on the background, I assume you are using Solidity to code your smart contracts.

The official online [Solidity IDE called Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) enables you to simulate the blockchain within the browser via the Javascript VM.

Simply go to the *Run* tab, select the `Javascript VM` option and then you can interact with and deploy the contract using the buttons that appear on that tab as showcased below:

[image: Remix IDE Run Tab Image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not relying any Quorum specific features of EVM you can easily use 
Ethereum testrpc chains.

With Populus and Python:

http://populus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html

With JavaScript:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli

Answer (score 0):

The jpmorganchase quorum package has a simulated backend module that can be used to emulate a blockchain for testing purposes without having to run anything.

Keep in mind tools like truffle, and ganache will actually run test blockchain, whereas the simulated backend mock blockchain only persists for the duration of your function calls and all data is gone when the processing is over. Truffle and ganache are quite useful if you want to play around with a more "realistic" blockchain simulation than using the simulated backend module.

https://godoc.org/github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/accounts/abi/bind/backends